# SQL value of one column based on max values in other selected rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the Northwind sample database table and I would like to find the top categoryId for each supplierId...

```
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| ProductID | ProductName                      | SupplierID | CategoryID |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 1         | Chai                             | 1          | 1          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 2         | Chang                            | 1          | 1          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 3         | Aniseed Syrup                    | 1          | 2          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 4         | Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning     | 2          | 2          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 5         | Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix           | 2          | 2          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 6         | Grandma's Boysenberry Spread     | 3          | 2          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 7         | Uncle Bob's Organic Dried Pears  | 3          | 7          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 8         | Northwoods Cranberry Sauce       | 3          | 2          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 9         | Mishi Kobe Niku                  | 4          | 6          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 10        | Ikura                            | 4          | 8          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 11        | Queso Cabrales                   | 5          | 4          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 12        | Queso Manchego La Pastora        | 5          | 4          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 13        | Konbu                            | 6          | 8          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 14        | Tofu                             | 6          | 7          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 15        | Genen Shouyu                     | 6          | 2          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 16        | Pavlova                          | 7          | 3          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 17        | Alice Mutton                     | 7          | 6          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 18        | Carnarvon Tigers                 | 7          | 8          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 19        | Teatime Chocolate Biscuits       | 8          | 3          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 20        | Sir Rodney's Marmalade           | 8          | 3          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 21        | Sir Rodney's Scones              | 8          | 3          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 22        | Gustaf's Knäckebröd              | 9          | 5          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 23        | Tunnbröd                         | 9          | 5          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 24        | Guaraná Fantástica               | 10         | 1          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 25        | NuNuCa Nuß-Nougat-Creme          | 11         | 3          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 26        | Gumbär Gummibärchen              | 11         | 3          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 27        | Schoggi Schokolade               | 11         | 3          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 28        | Rössle Sauerkraut                | 12         | 7          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 29        | Thüringer Rostbratwurst          | 12         | 6          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 30        | Nord-Ost Matjeshering            | 13         | 8          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 31        | Gorgonzola Telino                | 14         | 4          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 32        | Mascarpone Fabioli               | 14         | 4          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 33        | Geitost                          | 15         | 4          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 34        | Sasquatch Ale                    | 16         | 1          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 35        | Steeleye Stout                   | 16         | 1          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 36        | Inlagd Sill                      | 17         | 8          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 37        | Gravad lax                       | 17         | 8          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 38        | Côte de Blaye                    | 18         | 1          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 39        | Chartreuse verte                 | 18         | 1          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 40        | Boston Crab Meat                 | 19         | 8          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 41        | Jack's New England Clam Chowder  | 19         | 8          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 42        | Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee    | 20         | 5          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 43        | Ipoh Coffee                      | 20         | 1          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 44        | Gula Malacca                     | 20         | 2          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 45        | Rogede sild                      | 21         | 8          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 46        | Spegesild                        | 21         | 8          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 47        | Zaanse koeken                    | 22         | 3          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 48        | Chocolade                        | 22         | 3          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 49        | Maxilaku                         | 23         | 3          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 50        | Valkoinen suklaa                 | 23         | 3          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 51        | Manjimup Dried Apples            | 24         | 7          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 52        | Filo Mix                         | 24         | 5          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 53        | Perth Pasties                    | 24         | 6          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 54        | Tourtière                        | 25         | 6          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 55        | Pâté chinois                     | 25         | 6          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 56        | Gnocchi di nonna Alice           | 26         | 5          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 57        | Ravioli Angelo                   | 26         | 5          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 58        | Escargots de Bourgogne           | 27         | 8          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 59        | Raclette Courdavault             | 28         | 4          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 60        | Camembert Pierrot                | 28         | 4          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 61        | Sirop d'érable                   | 29         | 2          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 62        | Tarte au sucre                   | 29         | 3          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 63        | Vegie-spread                     | 7          | 2          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 64        | Wimmers gute Semmelknödel        | 12         | 5          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 65        | Louisiana Fiery Hot Pepper Sauce | 2          | 2          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 66        | Louisiana Hot Spiced Okra        | 2          | 2          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 67        | Laughing Lumberjack Lager        | 16         | 1          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 68        | Scottish Longbreads              | 8          | 3          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 69        | Gudbrandsdalsost                 | 15         | 4          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 70        | Outback Lager                    | 7          | 1          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 71        | Flotemysost                      | 15         | 4          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 72        | Mozzarella di Giovanni           | 14         | 4          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 73        | Röd Kaviar                       | 17         | 8          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 74        | Longlife Tofu                    | 4          | 7          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 75        | Rhönbräu Klosterbier             | 12         | 1          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 76        | Lakkalikööri                     | 23         | 1          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 77        | Original Frankfurter grüne Soße  | 12         | 2          |
+-----------+----------------------------------+------------+------------+
```

Using the query

```
SELECT SupplierID, CategoryID, COUNT(CategoryID) AS Total FROM [dbo].[Products] GROUP BY CategoryID, SupplierID
```

I get the table

```
+------------+------------+-------+
| SupplierID | CategoryID | Total |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 1          | 1          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 1          | 2          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 2          | 2          | 4     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 3          | 2          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 3          | 7          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 4          | 6          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 4          | 7          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 4          | 8          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 5          | 4          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 6          | 2          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 6          | 7          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 6          | 8          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 7          | 1          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 7          | 2          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 7          | 3          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 7          | 6          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 7          | 8          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 8          | 3          | 4     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 9          | 5          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 10         | 1          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 11         | 3          | 3     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 12         | 1          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 12         | 2          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 12         | 5          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 12         | 6          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 12         | 7          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 13         | 8          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 14         | 4          | 3     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 15         | 4          | 3     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 16         | 1          | 3     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 17         | 8          | 3     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 18         | 1          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 19         | 8          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 20         | 1          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 20         | 2          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 20         | 5          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 21         | 8          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 22         | 3          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 23         | 1          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 23         | 3          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 24         | 5          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 24         | 6          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 24         | 7          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 25         | 6          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 26         | 5          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 27         | 8          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 28         | 4          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 29         | 2          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 29         | 3          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
```

As you can see supplier 1 makes 2 category 1 products and 1 catergory 2 product.  Therefore the first line in the query should read

```
+------------+------------+-------+
| SupplierID | CategoryID | Total |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 1          | 1          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
```

Next should be supplierId #2 which makes a total of 4 category 2 products.  The final table should look like this...

```
+------------+------------+-------+
| SupplierID | CategoryID | Total |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 1          | 1          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 2          | 2          | 4     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 3          | 2          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 4          | 6          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 5          | 4          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 6          | 2          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 7          | 1          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 8          | 3          | 4     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 9          | 5          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 11         | 3          | 3     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 12         | 1          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 13         | 8          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 14         | 4          | 3     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 15         | 4          | 3     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 16         | 1          | 3     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 17         | 8          | 3     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 18         | 1          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 19         | 8          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 20         | 1          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 21         | 8          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 22         | 3          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 23         | 3          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 24         | 5          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 25         | 6          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 26         | 5          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 27         | 8          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 28         | 4          | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 29         | 2          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 29         | 3          | 1     |
+------------+------------+-------+
```

I know a lot of suppliers only make one item for a given category and this isn't a great example but just trying to learn here.

Thanks

Comment: Northwind strongly suggests SQL Server, so I removed the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of row number based on partition by supplier and then use aggregate function along with row number for ranking. Then only select the one where you have more rows for a given supplier. I just took some part of your sample data and did it in this way.

```
with cte as (

 select  1 as ProductID, 'Chai'                            as ProductNmae,  1 as SupplierID,  1   as CategoryID   union all                               
 select  2 as ProductID, 'Chang'                           as ProductNmae, 1  as SupplierID, 1    as CategoryID   union all                               
 select  3 as ProductID, 'Aniseed Syrup'                   as ProductNmae, 1  as SupplierID, 2    as CategoryID   union all                               
 select  4 as ProductID, 'Chef Anton''s Cajun Seasoning'   as ProductNmae,  2 as SupplierID,  2   as CategoryID   union all                               
 select  5 as ProductID, 'Chef Anton''s Gumbo Mix'          as ProductNmae, 2  as SupplierID, 2    as CategoryID union all  
 select  6  as ProductID,  'Grandma''s Boysenberry Spread'     as Product_name , 3  as SupplierID,  2  as CategoryID union all         
 select   7 as ProductID,   'Uncle Bob''s Organic Dried Pears' as Product_name ,  3 as SupplierID,  7  as CategoryID union all         
 select   8 as ProductID,   'Northwoods Cranberry Sauce'       as Product_name ,  3 as SupplierID,  2  as CategoryID     )
 select t.SupplierID, t.CategoryID, t.total from ( 
 select supplierID, CategoryID , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by supplierID order by count(1) desc) rownum, count(1) total    from cte     
 group by supplierID, CategoryID  ) t
 where t.rownum = 1
```

Output:

```
SupplierID  CategoryID  total
1               1        2
2               2        2
3               2        2
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to generate the category counts by supplier, then you have to rank them from highest to lowest, and finally select only the highest. In the following query, I've done that by using nested queries:

```
-- Select only the top category counts by supplier
SELECT
    [SupplierID],
    [CategoryID],
    [Total]
FROM (
    -- Rank category counts by supplier
    SELECT
        *,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [SupplierID] ORDER BY [Total] DESC) AS [Rank]
    FROM (
        -- Generate category counts by supplier
        SELECT
            [SupplierID],
            [CategoryID],
            COUNT(*) AS [Total]
        FROM [Products]
        GROUP BY
            [SupplierID],
            [CategoryID]
    ) AS SupplierCategoryCounts
) AS RankedSupplierCategoryCounts
WHERE [Rank] = 1
ORDER BY [SupplierID]
```

Comment: Note that `RANK()` will select more than one row if there are multiple categories with the same count per supplier. If you only want one row per supplier, use `ROW_NUMBER()`, preferably with a further `ORDER BY` column to ensure consistent return values.

Comment: I'm afraid this code gives the same results I am currently getting.  It shows the count for each SupplierID and CategoryID pair but not the CategoryID with the most products per SupplierID.  The expected output should only be 29 rows.

Comment: @GuyFawkes apologies, there was a small bug in the code, please try it now kepping in mind my note about `RANK` vs `ROW_NUMBER`

Answer (score 0):

In Sql server you can write a query as:

```
select SupplierID , 
        CategoryID ,
        Total 
from (
select 
        SupplierID , 
        CategoryID ,
        Total ,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by SupplierID order by  Total desc) as rownum
from (
        SELECT SupplierID
            , CategoryID
            , COUNT(CategoryID) AS Total 
        FROM [dbo].[Products]
        GROUP BY CategoryID, SupplierID
        ) as Innertable

) as Outertable
where rownum = 1
order by SupplierID
```